# How to send windows home key + "i" in Sikuli?

Tags: ubuntu, sikuli

I tried the following:

1. type("i", Key.WIN)
2. type("i", KeyModifier.WIN)
3. keyDown(Key.WIN)
   type("i")
   keyUp(Key.WIN)

None of them worked. It behaved like I just sent the windows home key to sikuli and it poped up the search menu in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this forever ago, but have you tried using Key.META instead? It's supposed to by synonymous with Key.WIN (or Key.CMD for that matter). I'm sorry, I don't know much about Ubuntu, or its interaction with sikuli...

I'm sure this is also too elementary to be of help, but you have made sure that NUM_LOCK is off, right? ('cause that tends to throw bugs with KeyModifiers, too.)

Which version of sikuli are you using? There are some known bugs with these keys:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1000643

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is long unanswered. Also, it was a bug in [sikuli for linux](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/966708).

I found a workaround for ubuntu. Since this question is asked ubuntu specific.

use the following option for `type("i", Key.WIN)`

```
run("xdotool keydown super")
type("i")
run("xdotool keyup super")
```